# cross compile for android on linux with __ANDROID_API__ predefinition fails my program

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I setup conan for cross building android app on my linux, i have my_profile below for conan for this cross building, which that I run `conan create . user/testing -pr=my_profile`

```
include(default)
target_host=aarch64-linux-android
android_ndk=$HOME/android-ndk-r21
api_level=21
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=9
os=Android
os.api_level=$api_level
[build_requires]
[options]
[env]
PATH=[$android_ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin]
CHOST=$target_host
AR=$target_host-ar
AS=$target_host-as
LD=$target_host-ld
STRIP=$target_host-strip
RANLIB=$target_host-ranlib
CC=$target_host$api_level-clang
CXX=$target_host$api_level-clang++
CONAN_MAKE_PROGRAM=$android_ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make
CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$android_ndk/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
```

and I made a very simple file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int raw_fallocate(int fd, off_t length) {
  if (fallocate(fd, 0, 0, length) == 0)    return 0;
  return -1;
}
```

I found that in the `fcntl.h`, it only defines `fallocate` when `__ANDROID_API >=21` with `#ifdef`
so in my `CMakeLists.txt`, I need to  put
`target_compile_definitions(hello PRIVATE __ANDROID_API__=21)` to make it compile, otherwise, the compiler will complain it cannot find definition of `fallocate`.

That all make sense. However, when I put this preprocessor definition, I still got a warning message saying:

```
In file included from <built-in>:413:
<command line>:1:9: warning: '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __ANDROID_API__ 21
        ^
<built-in>:405:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __ANDROID_API__ 16
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

What I don't understand is I could not find this built-in thing..., i searched my whole android_ndk folder, and could not find where is this `#define __ANDROID_API__ 16`

Also I only have android_ndk v21 installed, I have no idea where this version of 16 came from.

Any idea?

Comment: `__ANDROID_API__` refers to the native API level, not the NDK version. How are you building your project?

Comment: @Michael i am using conan to cross build that, with conan profile as added to the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `#define __ANDROID_API__ 16` comes from the NDK itself (this is the lowest supported API for **android-ndk-r21**. To set it to **21**, you must pass `ANDROID_PLATFORM` parameter to CMake. *Update:* this is actually wrong. For ABI `arm64-v8a` the minimal API is 21. So, the problem is that `arch=armv8` didn't work.

According to the [conan instructions](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#linux-windows-macos-to-android), `set os.api_level=21` should have worked. But with this approach, you should not supply the `CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`. *Update:* this does not work because `conan` is not compatible with NDK **r21**.

I assume that when you do supply `CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, all the settings, like `CC=` and `AR=` become irrelevant. Same for `os.api_level` and `arch`. But if you replace `cmake` with a [script](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-android_ndk_installer/blob/stable/r21/cmake-wrapper) that calls the original `cmake` binary and sets the necessarycommand-line parameters, including `-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21`, you should be set. Simply add to `my_profile`:
[`CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM=cmake-wrapper`](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-android_ndk_installer/blob/stable/r21/conanfile.py#L175)

This approach is used in https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-android_ndk_installer package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already have os.api_level=21 in my profile, and when i remove the line for CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE., i got error:   Android: No toolchain for ABI 'arm64-v8a' found in the NDK:

Comment: so i add `set(ANDROID_PLATFORM 21)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` but i still get warning `- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
16.`

Answer (score 0):

So I've been digging into this a little bit, and I think I found where the problem is. As @Alex Cohn said, the android ndk sets the min api level to 16 in the file
`$android_ndk/build/cmake/platforms.cmake`, it says on the first line `set(NDK_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL "16")`. After I change it to 21, everything works.

Now the question becomes: How can I override this value externally without touching this `platforms.cmake` file (I just don't want to touch files come with ndk package)? I tried to put `set(NDK_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL "16")` in my `CMakelists.txt` file for my project, but that does not work as I believe it is overridden later on by `platforms.cmake`.

Of course the second method of using `conan`'s ndk-installer also works, and I checked the same `platforms.cmake` file in the installed ndk folder, it has the same value of `16`. So there must be somewhere in `conan` settings that updated the value to `21`, and I would like to learn where / how this is changed when using ndk-installer, so I can do the same for my manually installled android ndk.

Comment: As I wrote, the problem is that the natural `conan` approach is not compatible with `$android_ndk/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`. In CMake, toolchain is file is loaded before anything else, and it sets up the rules. When you put `set(NDK_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL "21") `in **CMakelists.txt**, it's too late. The **conan-android_ndk_installer** package passes this setting as a command-line override to CMake, and it takes precedence.

Comment: It's a pity that `conan` does not support **ndk-r21**. The master branch is probably stuck at **r16**.